# JavaScript switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a game of Black Jack but I need some help trying to figure out how to switch the value of the Ace card between 1 & 11 as needed. This is the function that I have so far.

```
function cValue(card){
  if (typeof(card) === "string"){
    switch(card){
        case 'J':
        case 'Q':
        case 'K':
            return 10;
        break;
        case 'A':  
            return 11;
        break;    
    }
  }    
  else return card;
}
```

Comment: So either be `1`, or be `11` depending on what fits best for getting `21`? That can't be done with just a simple switch, you'd have to add up the numbers, and calculate what works.

Comment: remove `break;` as `return` statements are just before those `break;`

Comment: Set the ace to eleven, then test if the total is over 21; if it is, change the ace to one.

Comment: please add the rest of the code.

Comment: So I would need to write another function, outside of this one, that checks the total value of the cards in hand and changes the ace to 1 when needed?

Comment: yes, so it looks like.

Comment: @LennyG - I've now put exactly such a function into my answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply: it's at another point in the logic that whether the Ace needs to be 1 or 11 needs to be determined...

But adding the ability to choose in that particular function whether it returns 1 or 11 is simple enough:

```
function cValue(card, aceIs1)
{
    if (typeof card === "string") {
        switch(card) {
            case 'J':
            case 'Q':
            case 'K':
                return 10;
            case 'A':  
                return aceIs1 ? 1 : 11;
        }
    }    
    else return card;
}
```

That way you have an optional argument you can send to make the ace return 1.

```
cValue('A'); // -> 11
cValue('A', false); // -> 11
cValue('A', true); // -> 1
```

---

**However, whether or not that is useful to your program depends on how you're writing your game.**

You most likely need to do a lot more planning/structuring based around the fact that **after** counting the points you need to determine if there's aces in the hand and subtract 10 for each ace until you're under 21, and only if there's not enough aces to get under 21, THEN call it a bust.

Something like, if you have an array of card values like `var hand = [9, 'A', 'A']` you could have a function that calculates the total hand like follows:

```
function calculateHand(hand)
{
    var total = 0, aces = 0, card;
    for (var i = 0, ii = hand.length; i < ii; i++)
    {
        card = hand[i];
        if (typeof card === 'number') { total += card; }
        else if (card === 'A') { total += 11; aces++; }
        else { total += 10; }
    }

    while (total > 21 && aces > 0)
        { total -= 10; aces--; }

    return total;
}

calculateHand(['A', 8]); // -> 19
calculateHand(['A', 8, 'A']); // -> 20
calculateHand(['A', 8, 'A', 'A']); // -> 21
```

Comment: var lowCards = [2,3,4,5,6];
var midCards = [7,8,9];
var highCards = [10,'J','Q','K','A'];
var allCards = lowCards.concat(midCards, highCards);

var card1 = allCards[Math.floor(Math.random()*allCards.length)];
var card2 = allCards[Math.floor(Math.random()*allCards.length)];             var total = cValue(card1) + cValue(card2);

console.log(card1, card2);
console.log("Your total hand is: "+total);

Comment: That's the rest of the code so far. Sorry I don't know how to make it look right on here.

Comment: @LennyG - The function I give works for all those possible card values. And it makes more sense for you to store the cards in your hand as an Array anyway. It starts off as only 2 cards, but a hand could be any amount of cards as they hit. That growing list of cards is best represented with an Array rather than separate variables. A jsfiddle here shows it all working: https://jsfiddle.net/zvncevuz/